# how to count the number of iterations for loop java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have to implement this method that gives the number of Planets in the array "planeta".

```
public int size() {

    int size=planeta.length-1;

    for (int k=planeta.length-1;k>0;k--){
        if (planeta[k].name().equals(noPlanet))
        size--;
    }
    return size;

}
```

It returns the value of "planeta.length-1" and not the ones it's supposed to (for example, I add successfully 2 planets and it always returns the value I give to size when initializing it). What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I initialize the array "planeta" with NP, that means No Planet. When I add new planets they go to the first free position, starting from 0,in the array "planeta". Please help!!!!! Thank you =)

The addPlanet method:
    public void addPlanet(String planetName, BigInt x, BigInt y, BigInt z) {

```
    if(!planetExists(planetName) && !complete()){

        SpacePoint newSP= new SpacePoint(x,y,z);
        Planet newPlanet= new Planet(planetName,newSP);

        s=this.size();
        planeta[s]=newPlanet;

    }

}
```

How i initialize array "planeta":
private Planet noPlanet=new Planet("NP");

```
/** 
 * Creates a new Galaxy with no associated Planets and a given name
 * @param name the name of the Galaxy
 */
public Galaxy(String name) {


    this.name=name;


    //if the galaxy has no planets in it,it's array if filled with planet NP-No Planet
    for (int i=0;i<planeta.length;i++)
        planeta[i]=noPlanet;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Your iterator should be `k>=0`, not `k>0` - at present you're not looking at planeta[0]

Comment: How do I debug it? I'm new to programming!

Comment: Do you an IDE like Eclipse or pure JDK?

Comment: Where is `noPlanet` defined and how exactly?

Comment: In addition, if your array will contain planets from index-0 to index-i and not-planets from index-i+1 to index-n, then you can more efficiently count the number of planets with `int size = 0; for(int i = 0 ; i < planeta.length; i++) { if(!planeta[i].name().equals(noPlanet)) size++; else break; } In other words, you can break as soon as you see a not-planet

Comment: @JoanaSalvado If you are using Eclipse IDE then [Eclipse Debugging Tutorials](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)

Comment: Eclipse SDK. I've changed to `k>=0`!

Comment: Can you please post the code where you add new planets?

Comment: the problem is I have to return an int (it's what is asked in the project). After the break, outside the if, can I do `return size`?

Comment: Please add the above code to your original post.

Comment: If I add `break` it says that `k--` is "Dead Code" so it means that the condition is never executed, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the array like `Planet[] planeta = new Planet[12];` the length of the array will always the `12`. The array is already populated with uninitialized values. In this case `null`.

Use `ArrayList<Planet> planeta = new ArrayList<Planet>();` instead.
You can add new planets with `planeta.add( new Planet() );` and return the size with `planeta.size()`.

If you must stick with using an static array you should test if an index has a `null` value in the `for` loop and decrease the size when it finds one.

Comment: I can't use `ArrayList`, I've asked my teacher and he said he would consider it wrong, because the point is to work with arrays...but I've  try with it and it is better!

Comment: OP indicated that `planeta` array is being prefilled with `"NP"` planets, so there will be no `NULL` values there.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed that. This seems wrong `planeta[k].name().equals(noPlanet)` I think it should be `planeta[k].equals(noPlanet)`.

Comment: I've noticed that right now and I've chanded it, but it stays the same

Comment: is `noPlanet` the same instance everywhere in your class? You also could override the `equals` method to compare data (name) instead of identity (memory address).

Comment: Guys I just figured it out! I don't reeeeeealy know what I've done but it's working! Thank you very very very much for your help =D

Comment: If you post your working code maybe we can point it out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `null`s instead of special value objects, i.e. `new Planet("NP")`.
I guess this is something you are looking for:

```
public class Galaxy {
  // Empty array of size = 10, i.e. { null, null, .. , null }
  private Planet[] planeta = new Planet[10];

  public Galaxy(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int size() {
    int size = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < planeta.length; k++) {
      // Is there a planet or is it empty?
      if (planeta[k] != null) {
        // There's a planet.
        size++;
      }
    }
    return size;
  }

  public boolean planetExists(String planetName) {
    // Go through the array looking for that planet...
    for (int k = 0; k < this.size(); k++) {
  // NOTICE that we're going only through the non-empty array elements,
      // but we'll check for null either way.
      if (planeta[k] != null && planeta[k].name().equals(planetName)) {
        // Found it.
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Didn't find the planet.
    return false;
  }

  public void addPlanet(String planetName, BigInt x, BigInt y, BigInt z) {
    if (!planetExists(planetName) && !complete()) {
      SpacePoint newSP = new SpacePoint(x, y, z);
      Planet newPlanet = new Planet(planetName, newSP);

      int position = this.size();
      planeta[position] = newPlanet;
    }
  }
}
```

As for the debugging, most development environments (IDEs) have `Run > Debug` command along the `Run > Run` command. First you need to set a break point, usually by `Run > Toggle Breakpoint` on the selected line. Use `Run > Step into` and `Run > Step over` commands to go line by line.

Comment: If I change to null I get the `nullPointerExeption...` when trying to create a planet. I just can't see what I doing wrong!

Comment: NullPointerException happens when you do "object.member" and the object is null. Every reported exception will have a stack trace and the first line saying " at package.class.method (class.java:LINE)" you can use that information to locate the problem. Without full source code ("class.java") and the stack trace no one can help.

Answer (score 0):

This works! (at least in my case) I'll show you the changes:

```
public int size() {

    int size = planeta.length;

    for (int k=planeta.length-1; k>=0; k--) {
          // Is there a planet or is it empty?
          if (planeta[k].equals(noPlanet)) {
            // There's no Planet
            size--;

          }
        }
        return size;
}
```

And the method planetExists:

```
public boolean planetExists(String planetName) {

    for (int i=0;i<planeta.length;i++)
        if (planeta[i].name().equals(planetName))
            return true;

    return false;



}
```